# The Mathematic Tricks in the Derivation of Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm studying the derivation of Heisenberg Uncertainty principle but stuck with the mathematic trick.

When deriving Heisenberg Uncertainty principle, consider a function γ(t):
$γ(k,t)\equiv([t−(t)]−iκ[i\frac{∂}{∂t}−(ω)])f(t)=(T−iκΩ)f(t)$

Then,
$|γ(k,t)|^2=(T-ikΩ)f(t)·(T+ikΩ^*)f^*$

Let me omit the further steps. My question is:
Why $|γ(κ, t)|^2$ is equal to $(T-ikΩ)f(t)·(T+ikΩ^∗)f^*$?

Comment: it's just the complex modulus $|z|^2 = z z^*$

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Please don't post images of text and mathematical equations.  In the future use MathJax to edit your questions and answers.

Comment: No problem. I will try MathJax next time.

Comment: Please also this time.

Comment: Ok, I try to replace with MathJax. If there's any typo, please let me know.